# Grails dbm-changelog-sync No such property

Tags: database, grails, grails-plugin, database-migration

I am building a Grails app and was asked to integrate with liquibase.  After a bit of research I found that the Database Migration plugin is the preferred method for this. 
However, whenever I run any command involving the plugin, I get the following error:

> Error executing script DbmChangelogSync: No such property: database for class: _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy

I am using database-migration version 1.3.6.  I also tried with 1.3.8 but received the same error.

Any advice?  Thanks.

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Comment: I am using Grails 2.3.6

Comment: Have you tried a grails clean and grails refresh-dependencies?

Comment: Yes. I just tried it again after cleaning and refreshing the dependencies and it's still giving the same error.

Comment: Can you post your BuildConfig.groovy? I created an empty 2.3.6 app with the 1.3.8 version of this plugin and don't see the same error.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/h7ECYZ19